# Pytest for method inside class

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a python code that I am trying to write tests for.

```
class ship:
    def __init__(self, draft, crew):
        self.draft = draft
        self.crew = crew

    def is_worth_it(self):
        total_weight_of_crew = (self.crew * 1.5)
        x = (self.draft - total_weight_of_crew)
        if x < 20:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

I wrote the test below but it doesn't seem to work. How can I write the test with parameters of the method coming from the class?

```
def test_is_worth_it(self):
    x = ship(15, 10)
    assert x.is_worth_it() == True
```

Comment: I'm having trouble parsing this sentence: *"How can I write the test with parameters of the method coming from the class?"* What does that mean?

Comment: This code would work fine (apart from the fact that the assertion would fail because the result of the calculation is -5, which is less than 20). It's not clear what issue you are having.

Comment: just remove `self` argument of test function

Comment: Removing the self argument fixed it. THANKS.